# How to divide javascript logic for different pages right way?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, architecture, web, frontend

For example I have a website with some pages like the following sample:

- login.html
- user-info.html
- products.html
- product.html

I have different scripts for these pages. So I have:

- login.js
- user-info.js
- products.js
- product.js

I can concat these files into one or import with ES6 modules and get "scripts.min.js".

However if I have in login.js something like:

```
document.ready(function() {
   alert('Hello, this is logic for login.js');
})
```

then I get this messages for all pages.

I am searching for right way to divide logic between pages. All information about JavaScript architecture I found unfortunately was about SPA.

What's right way to organize JS structure in ordinary website to make it maintainable and scalable?

Comment: Uh... just don't concat these files?

Comment: There is no way to prevent this apart from manual checks, maybe based on the URL of the page, or by segregating the logic in AMD modules or so.

Comment: 31piy, Does modules helps to execute script only for target page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: If you want some code to just execute on specific pages you could do something like this (onload):

```
var _tgt = window.location.href; //where are we

var _is_login = _tgt.search("login");

if (_is_login !== -1) {
  console.log("Do something in login");
}
```

---

You could use node modules to trim your code:

- To remove comments and compress: uglify-js npm module.
- To combine various js files you could do something like this:

  1. Read in files using (eg) npm module fs-readdir-recursive and fs
  2. Remove unwanted content with eg regex
  3. Create a new file (combined)

Comment: Does any more beautiful way exists to do it?